# Retrieve params and set params as argument in fetch request within useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, parameters, fetch, use-effect, change-password

I am developing a MERN application. Presently I working on my Password Reset Emails, Validate ResetToken, Reset and Update password. So far, I have been able to complete All at the backend.

On the front-end, I have completed the ForgotPassword request which sends the user a mail with the reset token.

The problem is right now is that I  have not been able to retrieve the token at the front-end.

In my backend, the restPassword :

```js
userRouter.get('/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
        resetPasswordExpires: { $gt : Date.now() },
    }).then((user) => {
      if (user == null) {
        console.error('password reset link is invalid or has expired');
        res.status(403).json({message : {msgBody : "password reset link is invalid or has expired", msgError: true}});
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({
          username: user.username,
          resetPasswordToken: user.resetPasswordToken,
          message: {msgBody : "password reset link a-ok", msgError: true},
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

When tested with a valid URL like this, I get the right response

[image]

On my front-end my router is setup like this

```js
function App() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router >
                <Switch>
               
          ...

                    <UnPrivateRoute
                    path="/forgotPassword"
                    component={ForgotPassword} />

                    <UnPrivateRoute
                    path="/reset/:token"
                    component={ResetPassword} />

                    <UnPrivateRoute
                    path="/login"
                    component={Login} />
          ...
               </Switch>

            </Router>
        </div>
    );

}


export default App;
```

I try to retrieve the param (token) appended to the path (http://localhost:3000/reset/c25d7b114e99e8720761732eb1670a3d0a084877) in the email sent to the user so I can use it in my fetch request but so far I cant.

The console log of my response data is status 401 (Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/user/reset/", redirected: false, status: 401, ok: false, …})

Here is my code. Any valid solution will be much appreciated. Thanks

```js
const ResetPassword = props => {
 
  var url = new URL('http://localhost:3000/user/reset/?'); 
  var token = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/user/reset/'+ token).then(data =>{
      console.log(data);
    });
   
  },[token]);



  });
  return (
   <>
    </>
  );
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

Answer (score 3):

So after some digging, I got the answer,

First thing I had to do was to update my "react-router" and "react-router-dom".

From what I gathered, you need at least a 5.1.2 version to do this.

Also, ensure that you are running the same version for both dependencies.

So in my case, I have updated to

"react-router": "5.2.0",
 "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",

The next thing I did was to import { useLocation, useHistory ,  useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

```js
import React, {useState,useRef,useEffect} from 'react';
import { useLocation, useHistory ,  useParams} from 'react-router-dom';




const ResetPassword = props => {
  let { token } = useParams()
  console.log(token);
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
 

  useEffect(()=>{

    const currentPath = location.pathname;
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    console.log(currentPath);
    console.log(searchParams)
    
   
  },[location]);








  });
  return (
    <>
     
    </>
  );
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

In my router I have the route for the page set thus

```js
                    <UnPrivateRoute
                    path="/reset/:token"
                    component={ResetPassword} />
```

So the present browser URL is http://localhost:3000/reset/ab4794396674412e00406beda674349400c1f5ad

on the console as logged above. I have the following results.
console.log(token); 
result: ab4794396674412e00406beda674349400c1f5ad

console.log(location);
Result: {pathname: "/reset/ab4794396674412e00406beda674349400c1f5ad", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}

console.log(currentPath);
Result: /reset/ab4794396674412e00406beda674349400c1f5ad

console.log(searchParams);
Result: URLSearchParams {append: function, delete: function, get: function, …}